# bind base64 string to src image is not working with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´m trying to bind base64 data to `src` of img property. The code works fine until set the new value to the img vue property

I build this

```js
new Vue({

el: '#app',
data: {
  img: ''
},

methods: {
  upload: function( event ){
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    if( !file ) {
     return;
    } else {
     let imageType = /image.*/;
     if ( !file.type.match( imageType ) ) {
      return; 
     } else {
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function( e ) {
       this.img = reader.result;
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
    }
  }
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <img :src="img" width="200" height="200" />
  <input type="file" @change="upload">
</div>
```

Is not working, the base64 is set OK, but is not rendered to the image.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` context is changed inside of `reader.onload`.

Just store `this` inside a temporary variable like this:

```
[...]
const that = this;
reader.onload = function( e ) {
    that.img = reader.result;
}
[...]
```

Example:

```js
new Vue({

el: '#app',
data: {
  img: ''
},

methods: {
  upload: function( event ){
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    if( !file ) {
     return;
    } else {
     let imageType = /image.*/;
     if ( !file.type.match( imageType ) ) {
      return; 
     } else {
      let reader = new FileReader();

      const that = this;
      reader.onload = function( e ) {
       that.img = reader.result;
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
    }
  }
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <img :src="img" width="200" height="200" />
  <input type="file" @change="upload">
</div>
```

Comment: awesome sensei. It works too as `reader.onload = () => { ... }` and is not neccesary to create the const. Awesome orientation bro tnx